# How to make it so that your object doesn't move when you resize it

Tags: edit-mode

I'm trying to resize this cube, but whenever I do that, it moves out of place, anyone know how to fix this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the origin of your cube is still at the world origin, but your cube object itself is above the surface.

You can reset the object origin: Select the cube, go to Object menu, select Set Origin, then select Origin to Geometry.

Should solve your problem.

HTH

Comment: It might also be set to the 3D cursor in general.

Answer (score 1):

The origin is the pivot point by default and here it looks like the origin is no longer at the center of the cube geometry, so you can either change the pivot point (*Pivot Point* menu), or right click to set the origin to the object geometry.